# Creating a queue from a LinkedList in C

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

currently I'm writing a code which requires me to "copy" a series of integers(user input) from a linkedlist and place them into a queue.

I understand that I require a function called enqueue to proceed, however, I was taught that by simply using the insertNode() function, I can create a basic enqueue function. e.g

```
   void enqueue(Queue *q, int item)
     {
      insertNode(&(q->ll),q->ll.size, item);
      removeNode(ll,0);
     }
```

Given insertNode() :

```
 int insertNode(LinkedList *ll, int index, int value)
{
    ListNode *pre, *cur;

    if (ll == NULL || index < 0 || index > ll->size + 1)
        return -1;
    if (ll->head == NULL || index == 0) {
        cur = ll->head;
        ll->head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        ll->head->item = value;
        ll->head->next = cur;
        ll->size++;
        return 0;
    }

    if ((pre = findNode(ll, index - 1)) != NULL) {
        cur = pre->next;
        pre->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        pre->next->item = value;
        pre->next->next = cur;
        ll->size++;
        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

and then finally by using another function to make use of the enqueue()

```
    void createQueueFromLinkedList(LinkedList *ll, Queue * q)
    {

    if (isEmptyQueue) {
        removeAllItemsFromQueue(q);
    }// empty the queue if it is not empty
    while (ll->size)
    {
    enqueue(q, ll->head->item);     
    //code to remove ll->size by 1 each time 
        }
    }


    int isEmptyQueue(Queue *q)
     {
       if ((q->ll).size == 0){
         return 0;
      }
         return 1;
      }
```

The problem which I'm facing is that I am not sure whether is my enqueue() working correctly or if there is a better way of going about doing it? 
Thanks in advance.

definition of Queue, Linkedlist and ListNode; Suppose I'm not allow to change them :

```
typedef struct _listnode
{
    int item;
    struct _listnode *next;
} ListNode; 

typedef struct _linkedlist
{
    int size;
    ListNode *head;
} LinkedList;   

typedef struct _queue
{
    LinkedList ll;
} Queue;
```

Comment: This is what I would have done - have two pointers, `head` and `tail`. So your `enqueue` just uses `insertNode` using the `tail` pointer which points to the end of the linked list. `dequeue` will pop elements using the `head` pointer. Thus, you will have `O(1)` for both insert and delete operations.

Comment: Please show the definitions of `Queue`, `LinkedList` and `ListNode`.

Comment: @Bill Thanks! I have updated my code, part of the requirement is that I'm not allowed to add a tail in my definition of Linkedlist

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Just updated my code!

Comment: With my suspicion confirmed, I'm surprised you can build at all, considering that you pass a pointer to a pointer to a `ListNode` to a function expecting a pointer to a `LinkedList`. Are you sure about that call to `insertNode` in `enqueue`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg and if i pass (&(q->ll),q->ll.size, item); instead? My bad , I was ignoring the warning my compiler gave me. If i do not call insertNode function in enqueue, what logic should i implement in my enqueue given all these restrictions?

Comment: There are basically two ways of implementing a queue, both are using a linked list. The first is to insert nodes at the head, and remove node at the tail, the second way is the opposite. It's as simple as that. So there's really nothing wrong with your logic here, just your code. Use the list structures and functions you have, pretty much like you do now.